# Templating Headers and Footers with Custom HTML Elements

Tags: javascript, html, custom-element

i am attempting to show the same header (menus) at all my webpages. There is a youtube video on this. (same title as above).
but i cannot seem to get it going.
With reference to my code (mainmenu.js), if i attempt to enclose the part after this.innerHTML, i would get a error display of my VS Code.

[image]

Could this be the issue?? why the VS code error display?
index.html

```html
!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="center">
        <h1 align="center">Please Login  </h1>
        <form action='mainpage.html'  method="post">
            <!-- <label for="useremail">Email :</label>
            <input type='email' id='useremail' name='useremail'><br></br>
            <label for="userpw">Password :</label>
            <input type='password' id='userpw' name='userpw'>
            <br><br> -->
            <table align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="email" placeholder ='Email Address' name='' autofocus size="30" required>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type='password' placeholder ='Password' name='' size = "30" required>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type='submit' value = 'Login' size="30">
                        <input type='submit' value ='Forget' width='30'>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

mainpage.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Main Page</title>
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> -->

<script type=module scr=mainmenu.js></script>

<mainheader></mainheader>



</html>
```

mainmenu.js

```js
class mainmenu extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
        this.innerHTML = 
        <h1>
        test
        </h1>
        
        
        // <header>
        //     <nav>
        //     <ul>
        //         <li><a href="#">Lists</a></li>
        //         <li><a href="#">Sales</a></li>
        //         <li><a href="#">Purchases</a></li>
        //         <li><a href="#">Received</a></li>
        //         <li><a href="#">Payments</a></li>
        //         <li><a href="#">Adjustments</a></li>
        //         <li><a href="#">Reports</a></li>  
        //     </ul>
        //     </nav>
        // </header>       
            }
}

customElements.define('mainheader',mainmenu)
```

Comment: Are you inclosing it in single quotes `'` ? If yes try backticks ( ` )

Comment: at last some progress on my code. it worked for the backticks. no error on VS. but code does not work. the call the mainpage.html results in a HTTP Error 405.

Answer (score -1):

this is what you want to do

```js
class MyHeader extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
        this.innerHTML = 
        `
        <header>
             <nav>
             <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Lists</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sales</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Purchases</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Received</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Payments</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Adjustments</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Reports</a></li>  
             </ul>
             </nav>
         </header>
    `
    }
}
customElements.define('my-header', MyHeader)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <my-header></my-header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the mainpage.html will not use the javascript script? the js is suppose to be called by other html pages. It will be displayed as a common menu for all the pages.

Comment: very simple to do ```<script type="module" scr="mainmenu.js"></script>```

Comment: ookkk. i did. but i am still unable to call the page. (HTTP Error 405) Is there something wrong with the part the index.html; at the form get routine?

Comment: then you misspelled the path

Comment: seems to be a possibility. but all the files are in the same folder. also i pick the file from a drop down at Visual Code. I even resorted appending the full path (excluding the drive ).

Comment: Please try to open the file on "localhost".

Comment: Please explain (in the answer) how this solves the question